# File Location with Java FX Image and ImageView

Tags: java

Im finding that Java FX only loads the ImageView when it is located in the src directory of the project.  It will not load using an absolute path.

I am trying to load a picture, creating an ImageView based on an absolute path.  This method does not work:

```
ImageView imageViewFail = new ImageView("/Users/Ben/Pictures/javaPictures/raptorsRed.png");
```

I was able to load the file if I use the "file:" prior to the absolute path

```
ImageView imageView2 = new ImageView("file:/Users/Ben/Pictures/javaPictures/raptorsRed.png");
```

or if I get the URI of a File object:

```
File file1 = new File(path + "RaptorsWhite.png");
ImageView imageView1 = new ImageView(file1.toURI().toString());
```

I am not sure why I can not just use the absolute path first posted?  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: what OS are you working on?

Comment: Im using Mac OS